# new instance of the class in java main method

Tags: java

I am new to `java`, I was wondering why I need to create a new instance of the class to use its `non-static methods` in the `main method` but not in the other methods like the following

```
public class Test {


public  void test(){
    System.out.println("test");
}
public static void main(String args[]){

    test(); // error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method test() from the type Test
}
public void tst(){
    test();  // no errors
}

}
```

Comment: because `tst` is also a non-static method

Comment: Static methods bind to the class, not the objects. A non-static method binds to a specific object (or instance) of this class, hence in order to call a non-static method, one needs an object of that class. I recommend reading a tutorial, e.g. the [Oracle Tutorial on Object-Oriented Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java a class has fields and methods (or functions). Keyword 'static' can be added to both of these entities.

Entities marked with keyword 'static' are class related and other entities are instance related. For accessing static  fields or methods of a class we require only the class and its instance (created by using new keyword) is not required to be created.

Methods and fields which are not marked static belong to an active instance of the class.

Now suppose there is a class Test.java and we have no instance of it. We can call any of its method which is marked as static. Try thinking an answer to : "From inside an static method (without an instance of the class) how can we call a method or how can we access a field which belongs to some instance?"

For acessing non static field or method from an static method we need an instance. If the 'calling method' is non static then it must have been invoked on an object. If now we call another method from this non static 'calling method'  we can eaisly do that as that method will be invoked on the same object as on which the 'calling method' has been invoked upon.

As mentioned by Xavi in his answer you can also refer to 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html for understanding about 'static'.

All non static methods and fields have 'this' (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) associated with them, which refers to the current active instance of the class.

Hence 'main' method being static can not call any non static method without instance of the class 'Test'

Answer (score 4):

Look, `main` is `static` method. You call it from the class which hasn't been initialized yet. You can do that, however you can't call `Test#test` without having an instance of `Test`.

## Working code:

```
public class Test {
    public  void test(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test(); 
    }
    public void tst(){
        test();  // no errors
    }
}
```

## Explanation:

Non-static methods must be called on objects. Objects are created with `new` keyword. Sometimes, there are methods which return new objects, but they call `new` inside.

Static methods can be called without creating an object. You then need to declare  them `static`. How? Simply add `static` before return type.

## Example of how static methods work:

```
public class Test {
    public  void test(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        tst();
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test(); 
    }
    public static void tst(){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
    }
}
```

There were no errors in `tst()` because you called the method which you saw from that scope. It means that if there was an object of class `Test` created, you could call `tst` and `test`. If you tried to call `tst` before my refactor, you would have been warned the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

By definition

Static methods, belong to the class, meaning you can use them by calling

```
ClassName.methodName();
```

Instance methods (non-static) must be called on instances of an object of a certain class.

like

```
Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a non-static method from static area for this any how you have to create an object and through this object only you can call this method.

Or if you want to call directly the method from static area then make method also static.

**Why??** Normally in java there are 3 types of variable based on our declare position 1) local variable 2) Instance variable and 3) static variable, same as instance method and static method also.

**NOTE** Static method or block execute at the time of class loading and that time you are trying to call a normal method and the scope of normal method is same as the scope of object so, without creating object u can't think also about a normal/instance method.

Answer (score 1):

Think of static methods as existing outside of any instance of that class.  It is really an instance-less method.  In order to call non-static methods, you must reference an instance in order to invoke it.

Another way to look at the issue is from the point of view of the variables.  Static variables are shared by all instances of the class and do not belong to a single instance.

```
public class Test {

    private static int var1 = 0;
    private int var2 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test1 = new Test();
        Test test2 = new Test();
        var1++;
        test1.testMethod();
        test2.testMethod();
        System.out.println("var1=" + var1);
        System.out.println("test1.var2=" + test1.var2);
        System.out.println("test2.var2=" + test2.var2);
    }

    private void testMethod() {
        var1++;
        var2++;
    }
}
```

will produce the following

```
var1=3
test1.var2=1
test2.var2=1
```

Static methods are also shared by all instances of a class so do not have direct access to non-static variables.

Answer (score 0):

That's lesson 1: create an object from your class:

```
Test test = new Test ();
test.test(); // will print test
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main` is a *static* method, meaning it's not being executed in the context of a particular instance of the class.

Any method not qualified with `static` needs to be invoked in the context of a specific instance of the class, that's why it's necessary to instance an object or dispose an instance of the class to invoke if from a static context, or to call it from a non-static context such as your `public void tst()` method.

I'd strongly recommend going through some basic Java tutorials such as [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

To call static method, you only need the class,  while "non-static" we need a instance of the particular class(create an object of the class).